# CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:66 (message):

Tags: esp-idf, espressif-idf, esptool

error image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AqY1.jpg)

I am getting the following error when trying to flash the ESP-IDF firmware to my ESP32 device:

CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:66 (message):

Environment:

Operating system: Ubuntu on virtual machine
ESP-IDF version: 5.1.1
ESP32 device: esp32c6-devkitc- v1.2

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Made sure that the ESP32 device is connected to my computer and in the correct mode to be flashed.
Tried flashing the ESP-IDF firmware using the esptool.py command-line tool.
Tried flashing the ESP-IDF firmware using a different IDE or build system.
Tried flashing the ESP-IDF firmware to a different ESP32 device.
I am still getting the error message.
Question:
What can I do to fix this error?
[1/5] cd /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build/esp-idf/esptool_py && /home/ubu/.espressif/python_env/idf5.3_py3.11_env/bin/python /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 partition --type app /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build/partition_table/partition-table.bin /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build/esp32c6-blink-led.bin
esp32c6-blink-led.bin binary size 0x224d0 bytes. Smallest app partition is 0x100000 bytes. 0xddb30 bytes (87%) free.
[2/5] Performing build step for 'bootloader'
[1/1] cd /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build/bootloader/esp-idf/esptool_py && /home/ubu/.espressif/python_env/idf5.3_py3.11_env/bin/python /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 bootloader 0x0 /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build/bootloader/bootloader.bin
Bootloader binary size 0x5410 bytes. 0x2bf0 bytes (34%) free.
[3/5] No install step for 'bootloader'
[4/5] Completed 'bootloader'
[4/5] cd /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py && /usr/bin/cmake -D IDF_PATH=/home/ubu/esp/esp-idf -D "SERIAL_TOOL=/home/ubu/.espressif/python_env/idf5.3_py3.11_env/bin/python;;/home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32c6" -D "SERIAL_TOOL_ARGS=--before=default_reset;--after=hard_reset;write_flash;@flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY=/home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build -P /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake
esptool.py --chip esp32c6 -p Port -b 460800 --before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size detect 0x0 bootloader/bootloader.bin 0x10000 esp32c6-blink-led.bin 0x8000 partition_table/partition-table.bin
esptool.py v4.7.dev2
Serial port Port

A fatal error occurred: Could not open Port, the port is busy or doesn't exist.
([Errno 2] could not open port Port: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Port')

FAILED: CMakeFiles/flash /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build/CMakeFiles/flash
cd /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py && /usr/bin/cmake -D IDF_PATH=/home/ubu/esp/esp-idf -D "SERIAL_TOOL=/home/ubu/.espressif/python_env/idf5.3_py3.11_env/bin/python;;/home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32c6" -D "SERIAL_TOOL_ARGS=--before=default_reset;--after=hard_reset;write_flash;@flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY=/home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/esp32c6-blink-led/build -P /home/ubu/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar message only when I had another Serial monitor opened and connected to that esp32. When i closed that serial monitor it flashed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).